# wxPython SetLabel outside frame's class?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to use wxPython's `SetLabel()` in a class that's not the frame's class. Here's basically what I have for the frame:

```
class tradeWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Exchange", size = (500, 190), pos = (390, 300), style = wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.priceLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = x, pos = (84, 10))
```

Now I'd like to set the label of priceLabel from outside the class. Inside the class, `self.priceLabel.SetLabel(x)` can be used, but `tradeWindow.priceLabel.SetLabel(x)` doesn't work outside the class.

Comment: Could you post a minimum working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set class attributes outside the class, you'll have to pass a reference or use something like pubsub. Say you have a second frame that is spawned from the first frame (tradeWindow). When you create the second frame, pass "self" to it as a reference to your original frame:

```
self.newFrame = NewFrame(self)
```

Then in your NewFrame's init, you would have something like this:

```
def __init__(self, parentFrame):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="New Frame")
    self.parentFrame = parentFrame
```

Then you can just do **self.parentFrame.priceLabel.SetLabel**

The other solution is to use something like pubsub when you create a listener that you publish messages to. When the listener receives the message, it fires an event that you can use to set the label. You can read more about pubsub here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: But since it's got `self`, you can only use that in the class, right?

Comment: You use "self" to refer to the instance that is currently active. So the "self" in NewFrame applies to the NewFrame's methods. But you'll notice that we passed it "self" from the parent. That is the second argument in the NewFrame's init (i.e. parentFrame). Now if we make parentFrame into an instance variable by doing self.parentFrame = parentFrame, then we end up creating a reference to the parent frame that we can use to change or execute its methods and widgets